# Angular não atualiza tela

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

```js
angular.module("manuais", []);
angular.module("manuais").controller("manualCtrl", function($scope) {


  $scope.capitulo_itens = [{
    cod: 1,
    cod_capitulo: 1,
    tipo: 1,
    texto: "Titulo de um elemento",
    arquivo: ""
  }, {
    cod: 2,
    cod_capitulo: 1,
    tipo: 2,
    texto: "SubTitulo de um elemento",
    arquivo: ""
  }, {
    cod: 3,
    cod_capitulo: 1,
    tipo: 1,
    texto: "Titulo de um elemento",
    arquivo: ""
  }, {
    cod: 4,
    cod_capitulo: 1,
    tipo: 2,
    texto: "SubTitulo de um elemento",
    arquivo: ""
  }];

  $scope.limpaItens = function() {
    $scope.capitulo_itens = [];
    $(".elemento").remove();
  };

  $scope.insereItens = function() {
    $scope.capitulo_itens = [];
    $(".elemento").remove();

    array = [{
      cod: 1,
      cod_capitulo: 1,
      tipo: 1,
      texto: "Titulo de um elemento",
      arquivo: ""
    }, {
      cod: 2,
      cod_capitulo: 1,
      tipo: 2,
      texto: "SubTitulo de um elemento",
      arquivo: ""
    }, {
      cod: 3,
      cod_capitulo: 1,
      tipo: 1,
      texto: "Titulo de um elemento",
      arquivo: ""
    }, {
      cod: 4,
      cod_capitulo: 1,
      tipo: 2,
      texto: "SubTitulo de um elemento",
      arquivo: ""
    }];

    $scope.capitulo_itens = array;
  };


});


//diretiva que gera os elementos de acordo com seu tipo                                     
angular.module("manuais").directive("uiElemento", function($compile) {

  function link($scope, element, attributes) {
    var modelo = getTemplate( $scope.elemento.tipo);
        element.replaceWith($compile(modelo)($scope));

  };

  var getTemplate = function(contentType) {
    var templateLoader,
      templateMap = {
        1: "<h1 class='elemento' ng-click='selecionaElemento(elemento)'>{{elemento.texto}}</h1>",
        2: "<h2 class='elemento' ng-click='selecionaElemento(elemento)'>{{elemento.texto}}</h2>",
        3: "<p class='elemento' ng-click='selecionaElemento(elemento)'>{{elemento.texto}}</p>",
        4: "<div class='elemento img_container' ng-click='selecionaElemento(elemento)'><img class='figura' ng-src='{{elemento.arquivo}}'/><p>imagem</p></div>",
        5: "<div class='elemento img_container' ng-click='selecionaElemento(elemento)'><img class='figura' ng-src='{{elemento.arquivo}}'/><p>imagem</p></div>"
      },

      templateLoader = templateMap[contentType]

    return templateLoader;
  };

  return ({
    link: link,
    restrict: "E"
  });

});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 14px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 13px;
}
#debug {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="manuais">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="manualCtrl">

  <button ng-click="insereItens()">Preencher</button>
  <button ng-click="limpaItens()">Limpar</button>

  <div id="corpo">
    <ui-Elemento ng-repeat="elemento in capitulo_itens">{{elemento.texto}}</ui-Elemento>
  </div>

  <div id="debug">
    {{  capitulo_itens }}
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Criei uma diretiva que recebe o conteúdo do db e gera um elemento em html durante o meu ng-repeat.

Esta diretiva funciona perfeitamente quando há conteúdo, após isso, se eu limpar meu array "capitulo_itens" a tela ainda permanece com o conteúdo anterior. Isso acontece apenas se o array estiver vazio, mas se eu o preencher novamente a diretiva funciona e gera o conteúdo normalmente.

Agradeço desde já!

ATUALIZANDO: O problema ocorria pq a diretiva apenas travava os elementos, mas não removia os que haviam sido inseridos anteriormente. Conforme o código, utilizei $('.elemento').remove(); para limpar o conteúdo anterior;

Comment: Sua diretiva que se chama `uiElemento` tem que ser usada toda em minúsculo, separando as palavras por hífen. O correto seria `ui-elemento`. Só deixando claro que não sei se esse é o seu problema, mas é o correto.

Comment: Olá Gabriel Câmara, obrigado pela dica. Como havia falado, o problema acontece apenas quando meu array que é a fonte dessas informações está vazio.

Comment: Na linha `element.replaceWith( $compile(modelo)($scope)` está faltando um parêntese. Ademais, você recebe algum erro no console do navegador? Se sim, informe-nos.

Comment: Desculpe, durante as tentativas de solução acabei apagando o parêntese e não vi ao postar. Corrigido!